# Lua to c++, instanced functions for entity modification

Tags: c++, lua

I have been working on a simple component based c++ and lua game engine. Currently all the subsystems like audio and physics can be called from lua with there own module using `luaL_newlib`.

The problem I am having is how can a lua script call functions to modify its entity. Like `SetPosition()` is obviously going to need to be called on the instance of an entity rather than static functions. So is there a way I can have these instanced functions.

One idea I had was each entity registering functions for itself with a module name that is unique to it. So it would look like `entity1.Setposition` and `entity2.Setposition`. Would it be possible to register, effectively duplicate functions like this?

Or is there another way to have instanced functions like this so components can modify the entity that they are a part of?

If I have explained myself badly please do say so I will gladly provide more information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lua has syntactic sugar for "instance methods." If you call a function with a colon instead of a dot, like this:

```
entity1:SetPosition(...)
```

then Lua rewrites it to this:

```
entity1.SetPosition(entity, ...)
```

In other words, it adds an implicit first argument which is the object that the method is being called on. On the C side, you just see an extra argument. This is the preferred way to make instance methods.

---

Two other noteworthy things: the rewrite above isn't exactly what happens. If you do something like this:

```
SomeFunctionReturningEntity():SetPosition(...)
```

it doesn't rewrite it to

```
SomeFunctionReturningEntity().SetPosition(SomeFunctionReturningEntity(), ...)
```

It actually just calls the function once, as you'd expect.

Also, if you're writing an instance method from Lua itself, not from C, there's syntactic sugar for declaring one:

```
function entity1:SetPosition(...)
end
```

This is equivalent to:

```
function entity1.SetPosition(self, ...)
end
```

i.e. it adds the implicit first argument to the function, and calls it `self`.

(Incidentally, that's also equivalent to this:

```
entity1.SetPosition = function(self, ...)
end
```

Technically, even declaring a function inside of a table is syntactic sugar.)

Comment: I love you. haha thank you very much! I assume the object it sends as first argument is a table? could I define that table in c++?

Comment: @DavidC The first argument is whatever you call it on—table, user data, anything that you can use the `.` operator on. A table is a table, doesn't matter if you created it in Lua or C++.

Comment: entity1:SetPosition(...) will return a table to c++ right? or some other dataType

Comment: @DavidC It won't *return* anything to C++. Like I said last comment, it will *pass* absolutely anything as the first argument—whatever you call it on. Which is probably a table, but could also be a userdata.